# Find all but the first occurrence of a character with REGEX

Tags: .net, regex

I'm building a .Net application and I need to strip any non-decimal character from a string (excluding the first '.').  Essentially I'm cleaning user input to force a real number result.

So far I've been using online RegEx tools to try and achieve this in a single pass, but I'm not getting very far.

I wish to accomplish this:

```
asd123.asd123.123.123 = 123.123123123
```

Unfortunately I've only managed to get to the stage where

```
asd123.asd123.123.123 = 123.123.123.123
```

by using this code.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "[^\.|\d]*", "")
```

But I am stuck trying to remove all but the first decimal-point.

Can this be done in a single pass?
Is there a better-way™?

Comment: `s/[.]/\x{DEADBEEF}/; s/[^.\d\x{DEADBEEF}]//g; s/\x{DEADBEEF}/./;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done in a single regex, at least in .NET which supports infinite repetition inside [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?<!^[^.]*)\.|[^\d.]", "");
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!^[^.]*) # Either match (as long as there is at least one dot before it)
\.          # a dot
|           # or
[^\d.]      # any characters except digits or dots.
```

`(?<!^[^.]*)` means: Assert that it's impossible to match a string that starts at the beginning of the input string and consists solely of characters other than dots. This condition is true for all dots following the first one.

Comment: Thanks, this example has taught me things I never knew about regex.

Comment: thanks, I learned something new too! I wasn't able to understand the example until reading the link to lookbehind assertions! this helped me out too!

Answer (score 2):

I think it'll be done better without regular expressions.

```
string str = "asd123.asd123.123.123";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool dotFound = false;
foreach (var character in str)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(character))
        sb.Append(character);
    else if (character == '.')
        if (!dotFound)
        {
            dotFound = true;
            sb.Append(character);
        }
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank-you I appreciate this answer.  It hadn't even crossed my mind to attempt this sort of logic. I wish I could accept 2 answers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the regex you are currently using will leave any | characters untouched. You only need `[^.\d]*` since `.` has no special meaning in `[]`

After this replace, you could try something like this:

```
Replace(str, "([\d]+\.[\d]+)[^\d].*", "\1");
```

But you'd only need this if there is a `.` at all in the number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the first part.  According to http://regexpal.com/ your second regex would match all of 123.123.123.123 is that the desired effect? I've not seen "\1" used before.

Comment: Hmm, the second regex should match all of it, then replace it with \1 (which should be the first subpattern, the part in `()`) leaving only 123.123 - unless .NET uses a different regex system than I'm used to!